# Dynamic Asset Allocation Portfolio in R

Tags: r, assets

I intent to allocate equal weights of a portfolio of 2 mutual funds(Debt and Equity), based on their prices. The data I have is in [a Google Sheets document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1do-h_UHoE-rwEFL5_2KUZYgGUbGMwY03_gblAingUEY/edit?usp=sharing) and has typical stock like values. The requirements are as follows:

- Rebalancing of weights every 6 months on Jan 1st and July 1st.
- No units of any MF can be sold at any point, units can only be added until the desired asset allocation (50-50) is reached.
- Normally the weights should be adjusted based on prices on Dec 31st and Jun 30th, but it is possible that in the data there are no prices for those dates and hence the last available price must be searched for and used. So it is possible to go back (eg. Jun 28th) but not into July.
- Moreover, the prices used for both MFs should be on the same date. In case this is not possible in the data(highly unlikely), the nearest possible dates must be used.
- Finally two columns should be produced which indicate how many units of each MF fund were purchased on the different asset allocation dates and the prices at which they were purchased.
- Another two columns should be produced which indicate the final accepted weights (ideally close to 50-50) for every date, however since units are integer values minor variations are accepted.
- The final output as a CSV or Excel file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: R is vectorized language thus is a likely we could avoid the need for a loop here. It is not very clear on what your intentions are, can you explain what the desire outcome is.  If you could provide a small sample of the input and expected output that would be great.

Comment: ok i will edit this and post as a final problem. thanks.

Comment: check now... have updated the problem...

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).